# Too many temporary dirs created

Tags: python, jupyter, temp

Something running inside our installation of Jupyter Notebook is, in some occasions, creating literally millions of temporary directories named "u???.*" with only one empty file inside each one, named "socket".

The name of the directories seems to always start with a lowercase "u", and the extension starts with ".1" and grows to "9fshv" and continues to grow like this:

```
  %TEMP%\u700.1
  %TEMP%\u700.1\socket
  %TEMP%\u700.2
  %TEMP%\u700.2\socket
  ...
  %TEMP%\u700.9fshv
  %TEMP%\u700.9fshv\socket
  ...
```

They are created continuously at a rate of many per second.

Any idea what could be creating these directories?

I have already tried to search for clues in the code of the hundreds of packages installed, but "socket" is a pretty common word :(

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

It seems these folders are created when a zmq context is created (zmq version 20.0.1).

In another conda environment, where pyzmq is newer (22.2.1), that doesn't occur.

Comment: Maybe see if there is an import of `tempfile` somewhere?  Where are the temporary directories being created?  Which OS are you on?

Comment: I'm on Windows. The directories are created on C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp (default temp dir). I've just found out that just openning Spyder creates about 50 of these directories.

Comment: I think I've found it: just impor zmq and create a zmq.Context() instance and a directory exactly like that will be created. Now I think I can drill down into it to find out what is happening.

Comment: I was able to solve that by updating PYZQM to a newer version. Thanks!